# ETCD export as json and decode from base64 all key/values to human readable

Tags: json, kubernetes, base64, jq, etcd

Is there any easy command line option to export my entire ETCD database to json file but also  decode the keys and values automatically from base64?

What I succeeded to the moment is this(example show 1x key/value):

```
   ./etcdctl get "" --prefix -w json | jq -r ".[] | .[]  "
 {
 "key": "YnktZGV2L21ldGEvc25hcHNob3RzL3Jvb3QtY29vcmQvcGFydGl0aW9ucy80NDAwNDc0MjQ2MTgzNjUxNzAvNDQwMDQ3NDI0NjE4MzY1MTcxX3RzNDQwMDQ5NDg5ODkxODE5NTI0",
"create_revision": 44536,
"mod_revision": 44536,
"version": 1,
"value": "CPOB0OXRmdeNBhIIX2RlZmF1bHQYhIDgxN/V140GIPKB0OXRmdeNBg=="
}
```

But I need to decode the entire database keys and values to human readable format?

Thanks

P.S.
Final solution after @Jeff Mercado help:

```
1. /etcdctl get "" --prefix -w json | jq '.[]' > etcd_filter.txt
2. Clear output to form array of objects [{},{} ...{}]
3. cat etcd_filter.txt | jq '.[] | (.key, .value) |= @base64d'
```

[jq playground](https://jqplay.org/s/rglpDglWHNB)

Comment: Try adding `| (.key, .value) |= @base64d` to your jq filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the encoded data is a string and not binary data, you can decode it to a UTF-8 string using the `@base64d` filter. This should be available in jq 1.6.

```
$ ./etcdctl ... | jq '.[][] | (.key, .value) |= @base64d'
{
  "key": "by-dev/meta/snapshots/root-coord/partitions/440047424618365170/440047424618365171_ts440049489891819524",
  "create_revision": 44536,
  "mod_revision": 44536,
  "version": 1,
  "value": "\b���љ׍\u0006\u0012\b_default\u0018������׍\u0006 ���љ׍\u0006"
}
```

It appears the value is not a UTF-8 string in your example so beware. Unfortunately, it doesn't return a byte array so it may not be very useful for these cases.

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/HV4PtqYSnPi)

Comment: Thanks alot! This seems to do the job , I need it only for orientation what is stored in the ETCD , data will not be used for any other post processing afterwards ...